# Is there any event for phone lock?

Tags: android, events

I need to start a service once the phone is unlocked; is there any way to check the phone is in lock state, not screen on/off?

I'd like this to be the same as we do for screen on/off: we register a broadcast receiver. Can we register broadcast receiver for lock/unlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other event other than below:

Have a Broadcast Reciever for "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" and "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF".